# Investigation to assess interaction of two predictors using R software

Tags: r, self-study

In preparation for my end of semester R exam, I've been working on the following CSV file which was modelled on R, which I'm currently having problems figuring out.

[image]
[image]

To investigate this issue I decided to introduce a bilinear variable (SxPR)  which is the multiplication of the variable S (power plant’s capacity) and the categorical variable PR (whether LWR existed on the same site previously) and this can be seen in the excel data.

My current model which I've been asked to 'add suitable terms' to in order to investigate whether there is good reason to believe that the impact of a power plant's capacity on construction costs might not be the same for plants that did have a LWR on the same site previously and those that did not is:
[image]

This gives the equation $C = -9752+ 140.3*D + 4.868*T2+ 0.4180*S- 86.49*PR+ 153.2*NE- 8.38*N$

So basically, I need to confirm that what I've currently done to solve this problem is correct or if not, what else can I do because I've had a lot of problems with this question.

[image]

I concluded that the results show the bilinear term (SxPR) has a p-value>0.05 which suggests there is no interaction between S and PR (since SxPR is not a significant predictor to the model). This causes me to believe the impact of power plant capacity on construction cost is not the same for the plants that did have a LWR existing on the same site previously and those that did not).

To support this argument, the Scatter Plot below shows the relationship between the Construction Cost and Power Plant Capacity depending on whether or not a LWR existed on the same site previously. The crosses are the plots of the Power Plant Capacity where a LWR did not exist on the same site previously and the diamonds where a LWR did exist on the same site previously.

[image]

[image]

Would anyone agree I'm on the right lines. Apologies for the lengthy question. Hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

I think your reasoning is sound. The interaction basically tests if your lines are [parallel](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/catcon.htm) (i.e. if the slopes differ for plants that did have a LWR on the site vs. plants without LWR). In your graph, the lines are almost perfectly parallel which supports the conclusion from your regression containing the interaction. What I might add: The *adjusted* difference between the intercept of the lines is about $86.5$ (the coefficient of "PR" in the first regression). And because the coefficient is significant, you have some evidence that the production costs differ between plants with a LWR vs. plant without LWR.